# Add a post or comment to Wordpress via JSON API

Tags: android, json, wordpress

I'm developing an `Android mobile` version of my website and I have a section, which gets all my post from my wp blog. This is working fine with `JSON API plugin`.

But I don't understand how to add a `comment` or a `post` via `JSON`.

Please, can anyone help me out here and show me an example of how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to do that too, I found to what are all variables we need to post the content as well as for add comment via android.
For Post data to wordpress you need a **"nonce"** value to get this use the following code

```
yoururl/?json=core.get_nonce&controller=posts&method=create_post&callback=?
```

here, core and posts are **controller**, create_post is **method**

once you passed this, you will get the nonce value, store that in a variable,  and use the following one to post the data

```
yoururl/?json=posts.create_post&nonce="+your_nonce_value+"&title="+your_title_value+"&content="+your_content_value+"&status=publish
```

this will help you to post the data, to check this, try the code in web browser.

For Adding Comment to wordpress you have to use the respond controller and submit_comment method in the code, along with this you need to pass the value of following variables in the code

1. post_id
2. name
3. email
4. content

I Hope, this may help for you.

If you found the solution, let me know

Comment: i will try out the options and see if helps out.. get back to you soon thankx in advance

Comment: and how to submit image ?